# Вечная консольная ошибка Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage

Tags: css, обработка-ошибок

Регулярно на сайтах, которые я делаю, вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at findStyleSheets (chrome-extension://diebikgmpmeppiilkaijjbdgciafajmg/scripts/content-script.js:1014:12)
    at chrome-extension://diebikgmpmeppiilkaijjbdgciafajmg/scripts/content-script.js:1052:13
```

Все вроде хорошо работает, CSS подгружается, все стили работают, никаких проблем нету, но эта ошибка вылезает регулярно. Откуда она взялась и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка вызвана новым обновлением Google Chrome.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a4ebe08c91e29140e700c7bae9b94f27a786d1ca
Он блокирует доступ к некоторым файлам css.

Мы не разработчики хрома , по-этому исправить её к сожалению не получиться.
Если всё работает, просто игнорируйте её.

И ждём следующего патча.

Comment: спасибо, успокоил)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка и сейчас есть в Хроме. Но если открыть сайт во вкладке инкогнито, то ошибок этих не будет. Так можно себя быстро проверить или клиенту показать.